# windows wakeup, run script and go back to sleep

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, wake-up

MacOS has a program called pmset which can start from hibernation and power off again.

```
# pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU 20:19:00 shutdown MTWRFSU 20:25:00 
# pmset -g sched
Repeating power events:
  wakepoweron at 8:19PM every day
  shutdown at 8:25PM every day
```

8.20PM I run a test that takes 3-4minutes and send a report to our CI system.

Is there any equivalent on windows? On windows I've gone the other way keeping it always on, but it wastes power when there is an old laptop just doing a few tests once a day.

I've not managed to do this with older(2013-2015) HP Zbooks/Elitebooks. Are there any windows laptops that can do this? Since Apple control both hardware and software they may do this.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown

Comment: Task Scheduler will wake from hibernation to run tasks. Note if no one is using the computer it will go back to sleep really quick unless your program says not too. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast-messages

Comment: I just posted a program inspired by your question. It runs a program and prevents sleep while the program runs. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html